# jquery error uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going through a JavaScript tutorial. I have to show the length of an array but on calling I am getting the above error.

```
var bio = {
"portfolio": [
    {
        "name": "Sambit Mishra",
        "role": "Frontend Web Developer",
        "contacts": {
            "mobile": "+91-8888888888",
            "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
        },
        "skills": ["Awesome ", "Frontend Design ", "Javascript ", "Python "],
        "message": "Have a great day ahead."
    }
]}
if(bio["skills"].length > 0) {
$("#header").append(HTMLskillsStart);

var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace("%data%", bio.skills[0]);
$("#skills").append(formattedSkill);
formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace("%data%", bio.skills[1]);
$("#skills").append(formattedSkill);
formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace("%data%", bio.skills[2]);
$("#skills").append(formattedSkill);
formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace("%data%", bio.skills[3]);
$("#skills").append(formattedSkill);}
```

What I infer here is that the length property for bio["skills"] show as undefined. Help will be acknowledged. Thank you..

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `if` before that?

Comment: bio["portfolio"][0]["skills"]?

Comment: `bio["skills"]` should be `bio.portfolio[0].skills`. Don't you see that there are several levels of object and array before you get to `skills`?

Comment: Your inference is wrong. The error message is telling you that `bio["skills"]` is undefined, and you can't get the length of `undefined`.

Comment: @Barmar corrected it. Ya it is an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that `bio["skillls"]` does not exist. I guess that `bio.portfolio[0].skills.length` is what you want. `portfolio` is a property of the object `bio` with an array as value. The first element of this array is an object that has a property `skills`. The value of this property is an array and therefore has a length.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the path wrong. There's no property `skills` in the first generation of the object. Instead, the path seems to be:

```
bio.portfolio[0].skills
```

Or, if you prefer

```
bio['portfolio'][0]['skills']
```

Comment: As a point of clarification, this is the best answer, plus it was the first answer, so it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  `bio.portfolio[0]['skills'].length` or `bio.portfolio[0].skills.length` rathen then  `bio["skills"]`